# When is the Stack Exchange "day"?

Tags: discussion

I have a badge under way which requires me to post a question each day for five days in a row.

How do I know when the new day has started? (I am in Thailand, so I can't assume it is midnight my time.)

Comment: It's midnight UTC

Comment: Thanks, @Separatrix!

Comment: @Separatrix this is an answer, and indeed THE answer. So please post it as an answer and not as a comment. :)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin, it's not an answer without sources ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack Exchange day is the [UTC day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27201/162102).

The badge you're referring to, Curious, doesn't require that the five days be consecutive -- just that you ask well-received questions on five *different* days (and some other requirements).